# Hermitian Matrix with their eigenvalues arranged in non-decreasing order

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I need to formulate one property of Hermitian Matrices. It goes like this;

If A, B $\in M_n$ are hermitian and their eigenvalues are arranged in non-decreasing order , then

$\lambda_i(A+B)\leq min\{\lambda_j(A)+\lambda_k(B): j+k=i+n\}  i\in \{1,.....,n\}$

Thank you for your assistance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just rephrasing the Weyl's theorem which says that
$$
\lambda_i(A+B)\leq\lambda_{i+j}(A)+\lambda_{n-j}(B), \quad j=0,\ldots,n-i.
$$
Set $i+j=k$ and $n-j=l$, clearly $k+l=i+j+n-j=n+i$, to get
$$
\lambda_i(A+B)\leq\lambda_k(A)+\lambda_l(B), \quad k+l=n+i.
$$