# Why $\lambda_i(X + Y) \leq \min \left\{ \lambda_j(X) + \lambda_k(Y): j + k = i + n \right\}$? for Hermitian matrices with ordered eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra

Please explain why $$\lambda_i(X + Y) \leq \min \left\{ \lambda_j(X) + \lambda_k(Y): j + k = i + n \right\}, $$ if $X \in M_n$ and $Y \in M_n$ are Hermitian and their eigenvalues are arranged in non-decreasing order.

Thank you so much in advance

Comment: This is a duplicate question of this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/764187/hermitian-matrix-with-their-eigenvalues-arranged-in-non-decreasing-order?rq=1.

Comment: Thank you so much for the pointer.